# Woocommerce: How to add custom dependable amount to order total in admin order page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a particular (dependable) amount to the order total in admin order page. The amount is dependable upon the selection of a custom value (here custom value is city).So how can I add this amount to the order total in admin order page?

[image]

Comment: Do you want add custom fees after order placed? because I feel this should be applied before order placed at front side as well.

Comment: And also let me know how you stored your custom field value ? is it stored as custom meta value of that order?

Comment: We have done the front-end part and it is working well and it is showing in admin order page as well. So what I need is, when I change the city in the admin order page the order total should change accordingly